# How to parse the only the second span tag in an HTML document using python bs4

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing

I want to parse only one span tag in my html document. There are three sibling span tags without any class or I'd. I am targeting the second one only using BeautifulSoup 4.

Given the following html document:

```
<div class="adress">
   <span>35456 street</span>
   <span>city, state</span>
   <span>zipcode</span>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
for spn in soup.findAll('span'):
    data = spn[1].text
```

but it didn't work. The expected result is the text in the second span stored in a a variable:

```
data = "city, state"
```

and how to to get both the first and second span concatenated in one variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to slice an individual `span` (a `Tag` instance). Get rid of the `for` loop and slice the `findAll` response instead, i.e.

```
>>> soup.findAll('span')[1]
<span>city, state</span>
```

You can get the first and second tags together using:

```
>>> soup.findAll('span')[:2]
[<span>35456 street</span>, <span>city, state</span>]
```

or, as a string:

```
>>> "".join([str(tag) for tag in soup.findAll('span')[:2]])
'<span>35456 street</span><span>city, state</span>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
data = soup.select_one('div > span:nth-of-type(2)').get_text(strip=True)
print(data)
```

Output:

> city, state